# Yahoo Web Analyst / Bing Web Analyst

Tags: c#, web, watin, yahoo, bing

I have a project about get information form Yahoo and Bing analyst result
I want to access to `Yahoo web analyst` page and `Bing` also, But I can't find the address with analyst function? Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Yahoo Web Analytics, than it is discontinued http://marketingland.com/yahoo-web-analytics-to-be-discontinued-14223